# Regex in Java, finding start and end tag

Tags: java, html, regex

I am trying to find data within a HTML document.  I don't need a full blown parser as it is just the data between one tag.

But, I want to detect the 'select' tag and the data in between.

```
return Pattern.compile(pattern, 
                       Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE |
                       Pattern.DOTALL);

/// End right angle bracket left off intentionally:
track_pattern_buf.append("<select");
track_pattern_buf.append("(.*?)");
track_pattern_buf.append("</select");
```

Is this the 'regex' that you would use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want to stich with regular expressions (which are not the best choice) I’d use:

```
"<select[^>]*>(.+?)</select\s*>"
```

Comment: Hey, I tried your regex, it works for tags in one line but not multiple. Check here - http://regexr.com/38udu Can you help what to change so it selects tag across multiple lines

Comment: @NitishDhar `.` does not match line breaks; try `[^]` or `[\s\S]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would use something that looked like:

```
"<select>([^<>]+)</select>"
```

I'm not sure why you left off the '>'s and I wouldn't want to match other tags (here I'm assuming we're looking for textual data and not a document fragment).

That being said, I'd really look into getting a DOM and using XPath (or similar) to do your queries as regex's are not [well known for their ability to deal with trees](http://steve.yegge.googlepages.com/the-emacs-problem).

Comment: Leave off the '>' from the opening tag in case there are attributes.  I don't think there's a reason for leaving it off the closing tag.

Comment: This would fail to match any <option> tags inside the <select> since you are stopping at the first <

Comment: Those are some of the many reasons why I'd highly recommend you use XPath rather than putting together a nasty regex that works provided you don't actually care about attribute values, namespaces, entities, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think more safer would be to have something like:

```
"<\s*select\s*>(.*?)<\s*/select\s*>"
```

For more security you should probably add \w* after the first select in case any other select options appear.

Also the 3rd \s* could be probably skipped if your HTML is standard compliant.

Comment: If by "other select options" you mean SELECT tag attributes, \w* won't cut it. Also, I don't see any need to allow whitespace after the opening angle bracket. Unless the OP comes up with more detailed requirements, @Gumbo's regex is the way to go.

Comment: This will not match `<select class="mark">text</select>`, even adding `\w*`.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you don't think you need a full blown parser - we've all written an HTML regex parser at some point, thinking "My use case is so simple, surely I can use regex *this* time!"

But I think everyone who's gone and done it ultimately comes to the conclusion that just outsourcing the heavy lifting to one of the many excellent existing parsers would have been faster, easier, simpler, and safer.  I know I have.

Check out [jSoup](http://jsoup.org/) - it's simple, it's fast, and it works.  There's really no good reason not to use it.

If you're still not convinced, the fact that you had to come and ask what the right pattern was - *and you got three different answers in response - none of which do the whole job* - should be telling that the problem is much more complex than it seems at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, I would also recommend doing a negative look-ahead to make sure you stop at the first occurrence of select.

```
"(?<selectGroupName><select>((?:(?!select).)*)</select>)"
```

The important part here is "((?:(?!select).)*)" which takes anything that doesn't conflict with the negative look-ahead.

The same could also be accomplished by using a lazy quantifier:

```
"(?<selectGroupName><select>(.*?)</select>)"
```

These would both ensure that you will stop at the first occurrence of  preventing you from taking several sections at the same time. It does however not protect you against nested select tags, on the contrary those would cause problems with this expression.
With this expression the following would be an issue:

```
<select>
    <select>
    </select>
</select>
```

Without the look ahead or lazy quantifier the following would be an issue instead:

```
<select>
</select>
<a>
    <select>
    </select>
</a>
```